# Ajax get method does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, get

I have a problem, I am getting json data from an API,

```
  $.ajax({
    url: request,
    type: "get",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.ResultCode==="200") {
            console.log(data.Result[0]);
        }
        else if (data.ResultCode !== "200") {
            myApp.alert(data.ResultDesc, "");
        }

    },
    error: function () {
        console.log("your call failed");
        myApp.alert("Sunucuya erişilemiyor.","");
    }
});
```

this is my code I wrote, I have an error like

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

url is correct, I can't see the problem.

Comment: is this the complete error message? seems like a syntax error

Comment: looks like your resource is not supporting jsonp requests... see the response content using the network tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>change the `dataType` to: dataType: "json",</del>

As per your last comment:

> *i did write like this but i got error Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: **No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.** so i changed to jsonp*

This error occurs when a source has not enable CORS at its end to share data across different domains. If you have access to the source then enable the CORS then you will get the data.

Otherwise another option is to create a proxy at your server and call that to fetch the data from other server. For example in php you could do something like this:

```
//fetch.php
<?php
   header('Content-Type: application/json');
   $homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
   echo json_encode($homepage);
?>
```

Now you can call this file to serve the data:

```
var request = 'fetch.php';
$.ajax({
    url: request,
    type: "get",
    //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // not needed in this case
    dataType: "json", // <----this has to be json
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.ResultCode==="200") {
            console.log(data.Result[0]);
        }
        else if (data.ResultCode !== "200") {
            myApp.alert(data.ResultDesc, "");
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        console.log("your call failed");
        myApp.alert("Sunucuya erişilemiyor.","");
    }
});
```

Comment: maybe he is doing a `jsonp` request, this is no reason for error

Comment: firstly i did write like this but i got error  Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. so i changed to jsonp

Comment: Then that is error of CORS. The CORS has be enabled at the source otherwise you need to setup a proxy at your server to fetch the data.

Comment: @ElzoValugi `jsonp` uses some different type of data that looks like `callback({....data....})`. And in the answer it does shows that OP is trying to access json data directly. So, `jsonp` doesn''t make sense.